# Consecutive Vowels

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

**Potentially NSFW**: *[Consecutive Vowels](http://xkcd.com/853/)*

- Being a native speaker (6)
- _____ goin' nowhere! (3 4)
- Democratic Debbie (7)
- Major airplane manufacturer (6)
- Like the people in the linked comic (assuming bald means male and long hair means female) (8)
- Like Hal or Cortana (2)
- Go extinct (3 3)
- A sign of economic prospering (3 6)
- Victory (7)
- He ran with Palin (6)
- Comedy series by Szekely (5)
- Closest Hawaiian island to Hawaii (4)
- ______ in flames (2 2)
- Not weaknesses (9)
- He wrote rhymes just like these, he wrote rhymes with much ease! (2 5)
- Possibly a kid's first existential question? (2 1 3)
- A promise of return (3)
- Boyfriend (4)
- In ____ (instead of) (4 2)
- Cute, like old people (6)

Your answer is an alternate punchline -- or maybe hovertext? -- for the linked comic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Each of the answers

> has a string of consecutive vowels somewhere in it, and *only* that one string of consecutive vowels. (There may be just one vowel!) In addition, those strings are always made up of different vowels.

Taking these

> substrings, we can make a 5-bit binary number for each word. Take `AEIOU`, and write a 1 if the vowel is in that string and 0 if it is not. For instance, the first answer, FLUENT, has an E and a U, so the corresponding number is `01001`.
>  [image]
>
>  Read off the binary numbers using A=1, B=2, ... Z=26 to get the phrase **I WANT TO BE TOUCHING YOU** - which describes both the vowels and the characters!

Comment: Let's ban Deusovi from PSE for making us feel inadequate. Who's with me?

Comment: Also, maybe you could clarify that by 'string of ...' in the first spoiler text, it can be length 1 or more. I wrongly assumed 2 or more, and was thrown by 'Democratic Debbie', 'Sign of economic prosperity', 'not weaknesses' as I was looking for a string of 2 :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Good point - added that clarification!

Comment: @phylyp, that's a very good and popular idea, but as you probably remember, [we voted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/should-we-ban-deusovi-from-puzzle-solving) to use [honeypots](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58255/36023) instead :-)

Answer (score 4):

(partial answer)

_____ goin' nowhere! (3 4)

> You ain't

Major airplane manufacturer (6)

> Boeing

Like Hal or Cortana (2)

> AI

Go extinct (3 3)

> Die out

A promise of return (3)

> Bye

Comedy series by Szekely (5)

> Louie

______ in flames (2 2)

> Go up

Possibly a kid's first existential question? (2 1 3)

> Am I you? (not sure)

In ____ (instead of) (4 2)

> In lieu of

---

There are two clues which have potential answers with

> a lot of consonants:

Democratic Debbie (7)

> [Schultz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debbie_Wasserman_Schultz)

Not weaknesses (9)

> strengths

Those might be

> spaces in the sentence which is the final solution to the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

Being a native speaker (6)

> fluent

_____ goin' nowhere! (3 4)

> We ain't

Democratic Debbie (7)

Major airplane manufacturer (6)

> Boeing

Like the people in the linked comic (assuming bald means male and long hair means female) (8)

Like Hal or Cortana (2)

> AI

Go extinct (3 3)

> Die out

A sign of economic prospering (3 6)

Victory (7)

> Triumph

He ran with Palin (6)

> McCain

Comedy series by Szekely (5)

> Louie

Closest Hawaiian island to Hawaii (4)

> Maui

______ in flames (2 2)

> Go Up

Not weaknesses (9)

> Strengths?

He wrote rhymes just like these, he wrote rhymes with much ease! (2 5)

Possibly a kid's first existential question? (2 1 3)

A promise of return (3)

> Bye

Boyfriend (4)

> Beau

In ____ (instead of) (4 2)

> Lieu of

Cute, like old people (6)

Answer (score 1):

Potentially nsfw -- xkcd.com/853/

> So we probably need to find words with lot of vowels

Being a native speaker (6)

> fluent

_____ goin' nowhere! (3 4)

> you ain't

Democratic Debbie (7)

Major airplane manufacturer (6)

> boeing

Like the people in the linked comic (assuming bald means male and long hair means female) (8)

Like Hal or Cortana (2)

> AI

Go extinct (3 3)

A sign of economic prospering (3 6)

Victory (7)

He ran with Palin (6)

Comedy series by Szekely (5)

Closest Hawaiian island to Hawaii (4)

> Maui

______ in flames (2 2)

Not weaknesses (9)

He wrote rhymes just like these, he wrote rhymes with much ease! (2 5)

Possibly a kid's first existential question? (2 1 3)

A promise of return (3)

> bye

Boyfriend (4)

In ____ (instead of) (4 2)

Answer (score 0):

Another partial

Like the people in the linked comic (assuming bald means male and long hair means female) (8)

> Straight

Victory (7)

> <del>Succeed</del> Triumph

He wrote rhymes just like these, he wrote rhymes with much ease! (2 5)

> Dr. Seuss

Cute, like old people (6)

> Quaint