# A Fairy-ly Odd Chess Identification Puzzle

Tags: chess

I had an odd idea. I made a mate in two that uses a fairy chess piece. However, the twist is that you must figure what fairy piece is going to be used (changing a piece or by promotion) or is being used based on the position and stipulation.

Mate In 2, Black To Move

Black’s 7th rank pawns move upward (Thanks for the help @Gareth McCaughan!)

[image: FEN: 8/1p5p/8/8/2p1k1p1/8/3PKP2/2b3q1 b - - 0 1]

Identify the fairy piece that will be promoted, and state why. You must also solve the mate in two.

Comment: Just to be explicit: this position is shown from _Black's_ perspective, right? (Otherwise it's hard to see how any promotion can be relevant to a mate-in-two puzzle starting here.)

Comment: Well, if you give me a FEN, I'll paste the image in if I'm still online

Comment: This puzzle would very likely benefit from a major redesign; the basic idea (I assume there's a french-named capture involved) is solid, but in addition to the bizarre stuff with the black pawns promoting on the 8th rank, it can't be black's turn to move because otherwise white's previous move could only have started at an illegal position.

Comment: i think i have noti**c**ed another flaw... thanks!

Comment: @RewanDemontay ah, you are correct. The point still stands, though :-)

Comment: Can the black bishop just become a knight and put white king in check, with no move to get out of it?  If it must be two moves, the black queen can move to the corner first.  Or do I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1... h8=Nightrider+
>  2. f4  NRxf4# 
>
>  A  nightrider is a fairy chess piece that moves as follows: "A nightrider moves any number of the knight's moves in the same direction. A piece in its path of the opposing color could be captured, but the nightrider could not move any further."
>
>  Of course this assumes that for some reason the white and black pawns both move upwards, as stated by the OP.

Comment: @rewan But the white pawn on f2 needs to move upward to f4, which is strange if the black pawn also moves upwards.  Perhaps if you changed the pawn on f2 to a rook, then the board could be from black's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming black pawns move upwards, I think promoting either pawn into a [Lolcat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74037/36023) should do the trick in one move.

Comment: So mate in one isn't good enough?. Hmh.