# Every Answer To All Puzzles Here - Secret Found

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> **BREAKING NEWS**:  The magic stone which reveals all answers on this site has been located!

The only known photograph of the stone:

[image: The all answering stone]

The Stack Exchange Adventure Club has received word that the "**All Answering Stone**" has been found! It is a sacred stone that reveals the answers to EVERY puzzle posted on Stack Exchange - now, AND in the future. Needless to say, this stone's value is immeasurable!

The location of the stone is deep in the jungles. The club must hire some professionals. Unfortunately, the contact information for the only four people who are qualified, has been all jumbled!

You must help by sorting out this mess!

Fortunately, we were able to recover all of the data, but it is entirely in random order:

[image: Data]

Here is some information that may help you:

**1.** The adventurer who is an expert in English is either Johnny Staxx or the adventurer who receives the $30,000 salary.

**2.** The four adventurers: 
 are Kenny, the person who receives 40K salary,
 the adventurer who is an expert in Archaeology,
and the adventurer who receives the $35,000 salary.

**3.** Marthe Mumms receives $10,000 less than the adventurer who is the Math expert.

**4.** Of the adventurers who is the English expert and the adventurer who demands $40,000 in salary , one is Bobby Bones and the other is Johnny Staxx .

**GO GET THE STONE!!!**
[image: GO GET EM]

Note: There is only ONE SOLUTION to this. So dear moderators, please do not put yet another one of my puzzles on hold. :)

Comment: I've downvoted this because (1) it is another fairly mass-producible logic puzzle, and (2) it has a giant unnecessary gif in the middle of it. (As I mentioned before, there seems to be more effort put into attracting attention with gifs and images than into making an interesting puzzle.)

Comment: I agree with Deusovi — there is nothing particularly "unique" or "interesting" about this puzzle, as you can create an infinite number of these. While these puzzles aren't "duplicates" (in the way that PSE defines "duplicate"), I consider them to be "duplicates" since they all essentially stem off of a single base concept.

Comment: Same goes for the "math equation" puzzles. You know, the ones like "use the numbers ... and the operations ... to make the result ...". I recall that several were closed/were really unpopular since they were essentially just the the same base numbers and the same operations, just a different result

Comment: In the OP’s defense, this puzzle is *technically* on-topic for this site, and it *could* be interesting/fun for people less skilled at these kinds of logic puzzles. I do agree with the issues over the presentation, however; at this point, the images only serve to distract rather than provide useful information. And the puzzle itself is quite bare bones and straightforward, so I’m not sure how much enjoyment even a novice solver would get out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By 2, Kenny and the archaeologist are on "low" salaries. By 1, the English expert is either Johnny or one of those; hence, either Johnny or Kenny. In particular, not Bobby, so by 4 we have Johnny=English and Bobby=\$40k. By 3, Marthe is on a "low" salary; she isn't Kenny so she is the archaeologist. Now, of the list in 2 we have identified all but one of the names; filling the gap tells us that Johnny is getting \$35k. We now know that our mathematician is either Bobby (on \$40k) or Kenny (on \$25k or \$30k); by 3 only the former is possible. And now Marthe must be on \$30k.

So the lineup looks like this:

> ```
> Johnny English     35
> Bobby  Maths       40
> Marthe Archaeology 30
> Kenny  Physics     25
> ```

Comment: Noooo... Just started working on this and now its answered... I even finished it :(

Comment: Sorry! Better luck next time.

Comment: Okay, as always great work @Gareth. However.... I need to implement a new time buffer rule on my puzzles for you... no answers are accepted as valid until a minimum of 10 minutes at least has passed. It is obvious you are a computer bot which access to every bit and byte. Touche.

Comment: No worries, @YoutRied , I am a developer at heart. Gonna figure out how to finish this function:  if(puzzler.name === 'gareth'){ stopTime(600000); puzzler.displayForEveryoneElse(); letThemGoIGuess(); } 

On a serious note though, can I add hoverable hints in my original puzzle post?

Comment: Maybe you should try [trapping him in an infinite maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58255/57742)? :)