# A Fractal Sudoku - SS#13

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the penultimate puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

---

[image]

---

**Seems like this grid has had some extra cells inserted**

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13UqG1i_5JBvq-s6cxhpf5z1_aWw0pEj8nQLut2QIC2s/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**RULES**:

- Normal Sudoku rules apply
- The greyed out cells are empty

---

Almost at the end! One more to go after this, hopefully people have enjoyed! I know this isn't actually a fractal, but the grey pattern reminds me of that sort of shape :)

Enjoy!

Comment: Aww. I clicked on this hoping to find a real fractal grid-deduction puzzle, maybe something like the [Deusovi honeypot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58255/5373), but it's just a Sudoku with extra cells :-(

Comment: @Randal'Thor sorry to disappoint! I'm taking a lot of notes and learning a lot from the feedback from these, and the most obvious thing I've learnt so far is people reallllly prefer 'normal grid, different mechanice' than 'normal mechanic, different grid'. I'm trying to see if this is possible, and if its something you'd like to see I will def keep that in mind for future sudokus :)

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's actually *workable* for a grid-deduction puzzle, but I like fractals in general and I still remember the Deusovi honeypot puzzle for that fractal feature, so it'd be amazing if you could manage a really fractal Sudoku. Anyway great work with creating all these! It's a pretty impressive rate you're churning them out at.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have a couple ideas churning.. might have to bend the rules slightly to make it work. Anything which has some sort of infinite feature is cool in my opinion :P This series has given me a couple ideas for bigger and better versions of a couple of these, which I'll def have to look into further. And thanks! I made all of these quite a while ago, over christmas, so the only thing I've had to stress about is just writing them up :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterating over rows:

> [image: fractal over rows]

Then iterating over columns:

> [image: fractal solved]

Comment: Correct! Once again, fairly easy, just a normal sudoku with the grid slightly different. The last one tomorrow is gonna have a completely different mechanic however :P

Comment: I was about half way through when I realized that the grid was 4 boxes by 4 boxes which I thought was a super cool twist; more sudoku to solve without increasing its difficulty too much!